# What's the probability two students present consecutively?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

During the last class period of the semester, each student in a graduate computer science class with 10 students is required to give a brief report on his or her class project. The professor randomly selects the order in which the reports are to be given. Two students have been working on similar projects and would like to give their reports consecutively. What is the probability that this will happen?

Here's what I have (pretty sure this is wrong): C(10,2)/10! (10 choose 2 divided by 10 factorial)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I found the number of 2 combinations out of 10 and divided that by 10! (factorial)

Comment: Not sure I'm on the right track...

Comment: Can you write what you've done in the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $10!$ ways to order the students. If we consider the number of ways to order the other $8$ students and the pair of students, then there are $2\cdot9!$ ways to order them where the two students present consecutively. Therefore the probability is $$
\frac{2\cdot 9!}{10!}=\frac{2}{10}=\frac{1}{5}
$$

Comment: Consider the pair of students as one student. There are $9!$ ways to order the 8 students and the pair and $2$ ways to order the pair.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain?

Comment: Alternate way to count: there are 9 ways to choose where the two students give consecutive presentations, 2 ways to choose which goes first between them, and then $8!$ ways to order the remaining students.

Comment: @DanielSchepler This gives the same answer.